# LINQ Left join on my than one field? I have the SQL working but can't convert it to a linq query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, left-join, inner-join

I wonder if anyone can help

I have a simple SQL Query which was this.

```
SELECT * FROM ITEM INNER JOIN CODES ON ITEM.ITEMID = CODES.ITEMID AND
        ITEM.CATID = CODES.CATID
```

This works great, so i created the following query in LINQ

```
from i in Item join  c in codes
      on new { i.itemid, i.catid } equals new { c.itemid, c.catid }
```

Works great, but they i realized that i actually needed an LEFT JOIN in place of the INNER JOIN. So the sql, which now works great!, is :-  (notice left join)

```
SELECT * FROM ITEM LEFT JOIN CODES ON ITEM.ITEMID = CODES.ITEMID AND
        ITEM.CATID = CODES.CATID
```

So now everything seems to work and i get back the data i require using SQL i can't figure out how to do a left join in LINQ and especially how to do a left join on more than 1 field - in my case itemid and catid

I wonder if anyone can lend a hand, i am stuck :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the direction you need to head down:

```
from i in Item 
   join c in codes on new { i.itemid, i.catid } equals new { c.itemid, c.catid } 
   into grouped
   from g in grouped.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new
   {
      ItemId = c.itemid,
      CatItemId = g != null ? g.itemid : "Empty"
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look: http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/left-join-right-join-using-linq/

The key is --> 
        into JoinedEmpDept 
        from dept in JoinedEmpDept.DefaultIfEmpty()